# JSON number output: OK to strip trailing zeros?

Tags: json

Is there any real world hazard to stripping trailing zero and decimal point from numbers output to JSON?  Outputting `2` instead of `2.0`

I'm not interested in hypotheticals. Do you know of any widely used JSON parsing libraries that would choke on seeing an "integer" value where a float is possible?

For example, a JSON array of number:
[2.4, 5.6, 4, 1, 0.12]

I'd like to minimize the char length of number values I write to JSON, but there are worries that this will confuse some bonehead JSON reader.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is being assigned to a variable of a floating-point type, trailing fractional components that evaluate to 0 are superfluous.

I wouldn't worry about your boneheaded JSON reader, nor would I worry about a few extra zeroes after a decimal point upsetting anyone or anything.